# Intuition on the higher order tangent bundles

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

The first order tangent bundle $TM$ can be thought of as the set of velocities at each point on the manifold.

It can be formally defined in one of two ways: it can be the set of derivations on the manifold or the set of equivalence classes of tangent curves.

I’ve read that the tangent bundle is itself a smooth manifold so you can then take the tangent bundle of that.

My question would be how that would work. When I think of the tangent bundle, I think of a bunch of tangent spaces and I can’t grasp how they make a smooth manifold. Given the smooth structure, how would a higher order tangent space be defined and what would it mean? I’ve seen $T^2 M$ be defined as the set of second order derivations, as equivalence classes of curves that agree to to their second derivative, and recursively as $T^k M \equiv T(T^{k-1} M)$.

How are they related, what would the dimensionality of these tangent bundles be, and what is the geometric intuition behind it?

1. How is the tangent bundle a smooth manifold?
2. What is the definition of higher order tangent bundles?
3. What is the geometric interpretation of them?
4. What math can be done with them?
5. Bonus: Could you explain the same for the cotangent bundle and its higher analogues along with mixed bundles like $T^6 T^{3*} M$?

Comment: To see that $TM$ is a smooth manifold, I suggest looking at a book on Vector bundles. The tangent bundle is an example of a general construction, by which we create smooth manifolds that look "locally" like the product between a base space, $M$, and a fiber, in this case $\mathbb{R}^n$. I suggest taking a look at Principal bundles by Sontz.

Comment: In view of @J.V.Gaiter's comment, to get a concrete picture of what a vector bundle is and why it is a manifold, try to convince yourself that the cylinder is a vector bundle (more exactly a line bundle) over a circle, and so is the Mobius strip. They are clearly surfaces, hence manifolds!

Comment: As for dimensionality, the definition $T^k M \equiv T(T^{k-1} M)$ along with $\dim TM = 2 \dim M$ (this is a byproduct of showing that $TM$ is a manifold) yields $\dim T^k M = 2^k \dim M$.

Comment: I can see how a cylinder is a line bundle over a circle. 

If you take a pair of points on different lines that are the same distance to the circle, they’d be close under the new topology, but how would this connect to the definitions of tangent bundles? What would a “curve” look like mathematically?

Comment: I would recommend that you look at William Pohl's "Differential Geometry of Higher Order," *Topology* **1**, 169-211. [Here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81945111.pdf) is a pdf (for now).